# How can a microsoft botframework bot mention a user in an adaptivecard?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, mention

Following the Schema explorer at adaptivecards.io, there is no schema available for a bot mentioning a user (and teams sending him the proper notification that he was mentioned afterwards).

See https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/ for reference.

We want to use the bot for proactive messages to our users. If a user gets mentioned in one other solution, we want to transfer that mentioning event to the teams channel conversation and leverage the ability of teams to notify the user appropriately.

Question: Is there a way to add a valid teams @mention to a channel member in a bot message using adaptivecards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioning users can be done in AdaptiveCards according to this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#mention-support-within-adaptive-cards

To include a mention in an Adaptive Card your app needs to include the following elements

- <at>username</at> in the supported adaptive card elements
- The mention object inside of an msteams property in the card content, which includes the Teams user id of the user being mentioned

The mention object looks similar to this:

```
{
"msteams": {
    "entities": [{
        "type": "mention",
        "text": "<at>John Doe</at>",
        "mentioned": {
            "id": "8:orgid:{org-ID-of-the-user}",
            "name": "John Doe"
        }
    }]
}
```

}

The ID to mention a user needs to be in this format: 8:orgid:{org-ID-of-the-user}

Comment: The example in the linked reference uses this, not sure where to get that id from:


`"mentioned": {
            "id": "29:123124124124",
            "name": "John Doe"
          }`

Comment: After trying it, the result is as follows:
1) the mentioning highlighting is as expected in teams desktop (blue "**Bernd Gewehr**"), while teams mobile displays a blue "**@Bernd Gewehr**"
2) both do not show the businesscard of the mentioned user when you hover over them.
3) the mentioned user does not get a notification, nor does he see mentioning hints in the apps like normal mentions would show. 
Anything I am still missing?

Comment: When I use the 29:userId from https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/{channelId}/members, the user is correctly highlighted, has a business card and gets correctly notified. Now how should we handle those IDs appropriately in our central user base? Is there any documentation about this?